# How do I host a next js app with godaddy cpanel?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, cpanel, godaddy-api

I'm trying to host a next js application on CPANEL. I've logged in to the cpanel but I can't see 'setup node js' on my application [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvDYU.png). How do I successfully host next js app on godaddy with shared hosting?

I then tried installing node js from the terminal and successfully installed it by following https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/. The problem is I don't know which step to take from here. npm install keeps terminating on the cpanel terminal. Even though I uploaded the code. When I run 'npm start' I get this error

`
NODE_ENV=production node server.js

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'next'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hozen@0.1.0 start: `NODE_ENV=production node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hozen@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output        above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

`

Also here's my server.js

```
`const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
createServer(async (req, res) => {
try {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

  if (pathname === "/a") {
    await app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
  } else if (pathname === "/b") {
    await app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
  } else {
    await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error occurred handling", req.url, err);
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end("internal server error");
}
}).listen(port, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
});
```

`

and my package.json
`"private": true, "homepage": "https://example.com", "scripts": { "dev": "node server.js", "build": "next build", "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js" },`

My site is a next js site with sanity CMS

Comment: Have you had any success?